# display an image in a form when the image name is selected

Tags: c#, wpf

New to WPF. I want to display an image in a form when the image name is selected from a combo box (Image is stored in a sql database that fills combo).

Would anyone know of an example as to how this can be done. I have added the code that populates text boxes when selecting from combo.

```
   private void comboBoxDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        string constring = "Data Source=tcp:****;Initial   Catalog=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*******;Password=******";

        string Query = "select * from tables where Name='" +  comboBoxDisplay.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ;";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                string sReid = myReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                string sName = myReader.GetString(1);
                string sPicture = myReader.GetString(3);

                txtReId.Text = sReid;
                txtName.Text = sName;
                txtPicture.Text = sPicture;

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: As framed, this can be done entirely in Xaml along with an IValueConverter of about 20 lines of code.  To get the best answer, you should edit your question to show the data type used to populate your combo box, and whether or not you need to query the db each time the selection changes.

Comment: Thanks I have made an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, users of this site prefer question authors to provide a bit more information that you have. We also like to see that you have at least tried to find an answer yourself.

However, as you are a new user, I will provide you with a complete solution. There are several ways of achieving this... I will show you one way and you can adapt it to your needs.

Start a new WPF project and add the following into your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Images.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Picture 1", 
"/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Picture 1.png"));
            Images.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Picture 2", 
"/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Picture 2.png"));
            Images.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Picture 3", 
"/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Picture 3.png"));
        }

        public static DependencyProperty ImagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Images", typeof(ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>), typeof(MainWindow), 
new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>()));

        public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>> Images
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>)GetValue(
ImagesProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImagesProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have created a `DependencyProperty` named `Images` to hold the image information. It is of type `Tuple<string, string>` and this enables me to add the name *and* the file path of each picture. You will need to adapt this to your system of having your images in the database. I suggest saving the images in a certain folder and then referencing the file paths as it is much easier than trying to load image objects into the `Image` control.

Next, put the following code into your `MainWindow.xaml` file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding SelectedValue, 
ElementName=ImageComboBox}" />
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Name="ImageComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Item1" SelectedValuePath="Item2" Height="23" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here I bind the `Images` collection to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property and set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to `Item1`... this is the name of the first `Tuple` property which holds the picture name - therefore, the names will be displayed. I also set the `SelectedValuePath` property to `Item2`... this is the name of the second `Tuple` property which holds the picture file path - therefore the value of the selected item will be the file path of the selected `Image`.

Also note that the `Image.Source` property is set to `Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=ImageComboBox`. This means that the source of the pictures will come from the `ComboBox.SelectedValue`, which if you remember, is set to the file path of the selected image.

Things to note:

You can of course replace the `Tuple` objects with your own classes as long as you update the names of the correct properties to use for the `ComboBox.SelectedValuePath`and the `ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath` properties.

Please also add any images that you use with this example code into a folder named `Images` in your application root directory. Also, unless you name them `Picture 1.png`, `Picture 2.png` and `Picture 3.png`, you will need to update the file paths that you add into the `Images` collection.

Comment: @user2631662, if you like Sheridan's answer, please use the 'Accept' button to mark it.  Doing so will tell other users that his answer worked; and will also help attract their interest in any future questions you might have because it shows you appreciate their input.